# Can "disclosure" be a synonym of "publication"?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

I am writing a summary of an article and I found myself using the word "publication" over and over again. I thought that maybe I could use the word "disclosure", what do you think?Can "disclosure" be a synonym of "publication"? As far as I read on the internet, "disclosure" regards the action of making new or secret information known.

Do you think that that´s correct? My sentence is "After the disclosure of the EPOSTL in 2007, the public provided an overwhelmingly positive feedback".

Comment: Hmmm, not really, unless the publication contained secret or heretofore-unknown knowledge, as that's pretty much what disclosure means: "the action of making new or secret information known." as you said. Simply publishing a document doesn't meet that definition, IMO.

Comment: Not knowing what an EPOSTL is, I can't say whether it's appropriate, but have you considered 'release'?

Comment: Epostl stands for European Portfolio for Student Teachers of Languages. It is a document basically.

Comment: Isn´t it new information?

Comment: Release..uhm isn´t that normally used for music albums? Can I say "the release of a book"?

Comment: This is not answerable by a dictionary. There are pages and pages of synonyms for publication, and very few of them are appropriate for this context.

Answer (score 1):

A *disclosure* is an act of revealing something to an interested party that was previously kept private (not simply unknown).

Publishing information is one way to disclose something, but not the only way.  And, it's possible to publish something where it wouldn't be a disclosure.  Thus, the terms are not synonymous.